# Titanium Android: indicatorColor property is not working Activity Indicator

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, titanium-android

I just tried to change the color of the Activity indicator in Titanium's android App and found that the property is not working as expected. I wrote the following code to do so :

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow(
{ backgroundColor : "#fff" });

var activityIndicator = Ti.UI.createActivityIndicator(
{ indicatorColor :"red"});

activityIndicator.show();

win.add(indicatorHolder);

win.open();
```

**Anyone with any answer??**

[Screen shot of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUU5e.png)

I'm using Studio, build: 4.8.1.201612050850
SDK : 6.0.1.GA
Type : Android App

Answer (score 0):

indicatorProperty works only for iOS. I believe the documentation on this property is not correctly written/verified.

In iOS, you can use this property.

In Android, you can use a custom theme having this below property set to your desired color:

`<item name="colorAccent">#f00</item>`

Note that this item property also changes color theme of many elements, so read **colorAccent** usages before using theme.

Comment: I tried implementing the tag in custom Theme but it's still not working in android.

Comment: Note that this is a Material Design property which only works on API lvl 21+ (Android 5.0+). This answer won't work if you're below this version.